# Position index always returns 0 in getView and the program breaks

Tags: android, listview

I am implementing a `ListView` and when entering `getView()` I'm always getting position 0.

This is my Activity code:

```
public class CompaniesActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ListView listViewCompanies;
    int categoryId;
    CompanyLoader companyLoader;
    ListCompanyDtoOuterClass.ListCompanyDto companiesDto;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_companies);
        listViewCompanies = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listViewCompanies);
        categoryId = getIntent().getIntExtra("IdCategory",0);
        companyLoader = new CompanyLoader();
        getCompaniesByCategoryId();
    }

    private <R extends ListCompanyDtoOuterClass.ListCompanyDto> void getCompaniesByCategoryId() {
        new AsyncTask<Object, Void, R>() {
            @Override
            protected R doInBackground(Object... params) {
                return (R) companyLoader.GetCompaniesByCategoryId(categoryId);
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(R companies) {
                startList(companies);
            }
        }.execute();
    }

    private void startList(ListCompanyDtoOuterClass.ListCompanyDto companies){
        companiesDto = companies;
        ArrayList<CompanyDtoOuterClass.CompanyDto> cc = new ArrayList<>();
        for(int i=0;i<companies.getCompaniesCount();i++){
            cc.add(companies.getCompanies(i));
        }
        final CompanyAdapter adapter = new CompanyAdapter(this,R.layout.company_item_layout,cc);
        listViewCompanies.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

}
```

And the next code is my `Adapter`

```
package com.example.cristian_franco.cic.Adapters;


public class CompanyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<CompanyDtoOuterClass.CompanyDto>{

    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<CompanyDtoOuterClass.CompanyDto> companies;

    public CompanyAdapter(Context context, int resource, ArrayList<CompanyDtoOuterClass.CompanyDto> objects) {
        super(context, resource, objects);
        this.companies = objects;
        this.context = context;
    }    


    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View vista = convertView;
        if(vista == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            vista = inflater.inflate(R.layout.company_item_layout, parent, false);
        }
        if(companies.get(position).getURLImage() == null)
            return vista;
        ImageView image = (ImageView) vista.findViewById(R.id.IconComapny);
        TextView name = (TextView) vista.findViewById(R.id.nombreCompanyTextView);
        name.setText(companies.get(position).getName());
        try {
            new DownloadImageTask((ImageView) vista.findViewById(R.id.Icon))
                    .execute(companies.get(position).getURLImage());
        }catch (Exception e){
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "valio", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        return vista;
    }

    @Override
    public Context getContext() {
        return context;
    }

    public void setContext(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }
}
```

And here is my Layout:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.cristian_franco.cic.CompaniesActivity">
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listViewCompanies"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    </ListView>
```

What can be the problem?

Comment: You didn't post your layout, but I would check that your `ListView` height isn't set to `wrap_content`, otherwise the `ListView` might end up requesting position 0 multiple times.

Comment: companiesDto = companies; check this line where you are using it

Comment: I solved this, the scroll make the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is incorrect scrollView in ListView the correct Layout is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">-->
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.cristian_franco.cic.CompaniesActivity">
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listViewCompanies"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    </ListView>
</RelativeLayout>
<!--</ScrollView>-->
```